# Rstudio session aborted after allowing R Bigquery to view/manage my data in google bigquery

Tags: r, rstudio, google-bigquery, dplyr

I am trying to connect R to Bigquery using bigrquery package and dplyr. Below is the sample code:

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "fantastic-voyage-389" # put your project ID here
sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM    [publicdata:samples.natality] LIMIT 5"
query_exec(sql, project = project)
```

R asks me to cache OAuth between sessions, and it brings me to the browser session where it asks me the permission for view and manage my data in bigquery. Once I clicked yes, the browser says 'authentication completed'. In the meantime, however, the Rstudio crashs and says R has a fatal error.

my bigrquery package version is 0.1.0, and Rstudio 0.99.486

Does anyone have same experience before?

Comment: I think I figure out the issue here, is the Rcurl version is not compatible with the bigrquery package. Once I updated my Rcurl package, the problem seems to go away. But a new error message shows up - invalid credentials.when I try to reset_access_cred(), it seems the old credential is still there. What can I do to remove the old one, and let google bring me to the authentication browser again?

Comment: If you're unable to clear old, bad credentials, this could be a platform issue which requires a bug report in the [Bigquery public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).

Comment: It might just be a case of clearing the data within RStudio, but in that case, you'd still want to report the issue since future users might see it.

Comment: I have tried to clear all objects within Rstudio, and also tried to remove bigrquery package and reload it, and sign out my google account, and clean cache on the browser. Nothing seems to work, and the bad credential is still there.

Comment: From looking into the issue a little more, I think the issue may be with the libraries themselves, not with RStudio. [Here](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/blob/cdb968d1b314999354bd37fc2224f54d791feec9/R/auth.r#L27) you can see the function which generates tokens in the bigrquery library, and [here](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/oauth-token.r#L196) you can see the function that function relies on in the `httr` library. Either your own pattern of calling the bigrquery auth functions is causing an issue, or the "cache" mentioned in httr is misbehaving.

Comment: As you can read in the second link above, "OAuth tokens are cached on disk in a file called \code{.httr-oauth} saved in the current working directory." Could you attempt to find such a file?

Comment: Yes, I think I found the file. and it seems to work fine now. Thanks!

Comment: :) The art of source-diving gets results! Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete [tokens cached on disk](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/oauth-token.r#L17) by the httr library's OAuth2.0 functionality.

If this issue continues to occur (ie. `reset_access_cred()` doesn't work), a manual fix like this is clearly undesirable, and an issue should be opened with the maintainers of `httr` or `bigrquery`, depending on what's likely at fault.

Comment: Yes, i will raise the issue to httr and bigrquery as well. Seems like bigrquery doesn't work with Rcurl 1.96 version neither

Comment: Author of bigrgquery Hadley mentioned that access_cred family functions is work in progress.

Comment: So essentially, updating the httr package from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 will currently break bigrquery (0.1.0)? That's at least the case for me.